# file type doesn't support .csv format in window chrome browser

Tags: html, csv, file-upload

I have an issue with input type = 'file'. It shows type with empty string when I upload .csv file(other file type works fine like, pdf, jpg,doc etc).

Example Url is

```html
"http://plnkr.co/edit/1dgAM3I71uzZEqDN3PbX?p=preview"
```

This above link works fine in ubuntu OS but not in window(chrome) and doesn't show "type" of file(showing empty string ). Is it not supporting the .csv format or having a problem with window chrome. I am using chrome's latest version.

Comment: <input type="file" accept=".csv" />

Comment: @Ved accept is use for validating file type, but in my case window' s chrome browser doesn't support .CSV format(it give me empty string). Check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/F5T7ZB7yQ10pyHw5ctic?p=preview

Comment: I too have ubuntu OS here. Can't test for windows chrome.

Comment: I have win7 and it is working with Chrome v 44

Comment: For me, windows chrome is showing the file type parameter to be "application/vnd.ms-excel" for csv files. It looks like there's an unresolved bug.

Comment: @Rajeev Yes, I have the same issue with latest Chrome on Window 8.1